# Resetting Modal Wizard to Original State When Input Field Clicked

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a form that launches a modal wizard when a user clicks on an input field to schedule a repeating job. This works as expected. However, right now, after the user finishes filling out the form and clicks "save", when the modal is re-opened for the next job, it's still holding the value from the last user activity. So I need to clear the modal wizard and make sure that it loads up step 1 of the modal the next time a user goes to schedule a job.

Here's the jQuery that fires when the user clicks "save". Notice I'm trying to re-set "#scheduleModal" here.

```
$("#save-job").click(function () {
  $("#scheduleModal").val(""); // This part doesn't work
});
```

Using `.val` may not be the correct way to handle this. What would be the correct way to set the modal back to it's original state?
Here's the opening section of my HTML block for the modal wizard. I'm not sure what to attach to here to clear the contents:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="repeat-every-div">
      <label>Repeat Every</label>
      <input type="text" class="job-repeat-every form-control" data-toggle="modal" id="repeat-every"
        data-target="#scheduleModal">
    </div>

    <form id="recurring-job-form">

      <div id="scheduleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="scheduleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
              <h3 id="myModalLabel">Recurring Job Details</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="recurringJobWizard">

              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">

                  <div class="well">

                    <label>Repetition Interval</label>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="daily" name="repetition-interval">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Daily</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="dailyM-F" name="repetition-interval">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Daily (M - F Only)</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="weekly" name="repetition-interval">
                      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Weekly</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="monthly" name="repetition-interval">
                      <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Monthly</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2"
                    id="secondStep">Continue</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="weeklyOptions">
                  <div class="well">
                    <label>Day of the Week</label>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Monday" name="day-of-week">
                      <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Monday</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Tuesday" name="day-of-week">
                      <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Tuesday</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Wednesday" name="day-of-week">
                      <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Wednesday</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Thursday" name="day-of-week">
                      <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Thursday</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Friday" name="day-of-week">
                      <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Friday</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Saturday" name="day-of-week">
                      <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Saturday</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Sunday" name="day-of-week">
                      <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Sunday</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#dailyOptions" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3"
                    id="finalStep">Continue</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2"
                    id="weeklyBackStep">Back</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dailyOptions">
                  <div class="md-form mx-5 my-5">
                    <label for="time-selection">Time of Day</label>
                    <input type="time" id="time-selection" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-default next top-space" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2"
                    id="dailyBackStep">Back</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="monthlyOptions">
                  <div class="well">
                    <select class="form-control" id="dayOfMonthSelection">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                      <option value="7">7</option>
                      <option value="8">8</option>
                      <option value="9">9</option>
                      <option value="10">10</option>
                      <option value="11">11</option>
                      <option value="12">12</option>
                      <option value="13">13</option>
                      <option value="14">14</option>
                      <option value="15">15</option>
                      <option value="16">16</option>
                      <option value="17">17</option>
                      <option value="18">18</option>
                      <option value="19">19</option>
                      <option value="20">20</option>
                      <option value="21">21</option>
                      <option value="22">22</option>
                      <option value="23">23</option>
                      <option value="24">24</option>
                      <option value="25">25</option>
                      <option value="26">26</option>
                      <option value="27">27</option>
                      <option value="28">28</option>
                      <option value="29">29</option>
                      <option value="30">30</option>
                      <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#dailyOptions" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3">Continue</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2"
                    id="monthlyBackStep">Back</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="save-recurring-job">Save</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

The HTML code for the "save" button that I want this event to trigger on is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-success save-button" data-action="save" id="save-job">Save</span>
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-warning" data-action="cancel">Cancel</span>
</div>
```

To clarify, the modal wizard opens when the user clicks within the input field for "repeat-every".

Comment: `$("#scheduleModal").val("")` won't work because `#scheduleModal` is a `div` not a form control. Can you provide the rest of the code to reproduce a complete example?

Comment: Okay, I added the full modal wizard code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a form reset using `.trigger("reset")` which is equivalent to have a button of type `reset`.

```js
$("#save-job").click(function() {
  $("#recurring-job-form").trigger("reset");
  $(".tab-pane:not(#step1)").removeClass("active show");
  $("#step1").tab("show"); // reset tabs
});
```

If the [form reset event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) isn't what you are after then you can opt for an alternative approach by targeting each form type.
This will reset your modal form back to its initial state or you can modify it to set defaults for the next time the modal is opened.

```js
$("#save-job").click(function() {
  $("[name='repetition-interval']").prop("checked", false); // OR $("input:radio") for all radio inputs
  $("[name='day-of-week']").prop("checked", false);
  $("#time-selection").val("");
  $("#dayOfMonthSelection option:first").prop("selected", true);
  $(".tab-pane:not(#step1)").removeClass("active show");
  $("#step1").tab("show");
});
```

```html
<!--<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="repeat-every-div">
  <label>Repeat Every</label>
  <input type="text" class="job-repeat-every form-control" data-toggle="modal" id="repeat-every" data-target="#scheduleModal">
</div>

<form id="recurring-job-form">

  <div id="scheduleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="scheduleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h3 id="myModalLabel">Recurring Job Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="recurringJobWizard">

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">

              <div class="well">

                <label>Repetition Interval</label>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="daily" name="repetition-interval">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Daily</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="dailyM-F" name="repetition-interval">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Daily (M - F Only)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="weekly" name="repetition-interval">
                  <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Weekly</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input repInt" id="monthly" name="repetition-interval">
                  <label class="form-check-label time-interval" for="materialUnchecked">Monthly</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2" id="secondStep">Continue</a>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="weeklyOptions">
              <div class="well">
                <label>Day of the Week</label>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Monday" name="day-of-week">
                  <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Monday</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Tuesday" name="day-of-week">
                  <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Tuesday</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Wednesday" name="day-of-week">
                  <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Wednesday</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Thursday" name="day-of-week">
                  <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Thursday</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Friday" name="day-of-week">
                  <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Friday</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Saturday" name="day-of-week">
                  <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Saturday</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input day" id="Sunday" name="day-of-week">
                  <label class="form-check-label day-of-week" for="materialUnchecked">Sunday</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#dailyOptions" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3" id="finalStep">Continue</a>
              <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2" id="weeklyBackStep">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dailyOptions">
              <div class="md-form mx-5 my-5">
                <label for="time-selection">Time of Day</label>
                <input type="time" id="time-selection" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <a class="btn btn-default next top-space" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2" id="dailyBackStep">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="monthlyOptions">
              <div class="well">
                <select class="form-control" id="dayOfMonthSelection">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  <option value="6">6</option>
                  <option value="7">7</option>
                  <option value="8">8</option>
                  <option value="9">9</option>
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="11">11</option>
                  <option value="12">12</option>
                  <option value="13">13</option>
                  <option value="14">14</option>
                  <option value="15">15</option>
                  <option value="16">16</option>
                  <option value="17">17</option>
                  <option value="18">18</option>
                  <option value="19">19</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
                  <option value="21">21</option>
                  <option value="22">22</option>
                  <option value="23">23</option>
                  <option value="24">24</option>
                  <option value="25">25</option>
                  <option value="26">26</option>
                  <option value="27">27</option>
                  <option value="28">28</option>
                  <option value="29">29</option>
                  <option value="30">30</option>
                  <option value="31">31</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#dailyOptions" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3">Continue</a>
              <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2" id="monthlyBackStep">Back</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="save-recurring-job">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

<div class="form-group">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-success save-button" data-action="save" id="save-job">Save</span>
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-warning" data-action="cancel">Cancel</span>
</div>
```

It seems that there is still some additional missing code which wasn't provided. For example, the tab content is missing a `show` class, as well as the code to navigate between tabs when clicking continue. I've commented out the Bootstrap CSS as these parts I just mentioned aren't critical to solve the question you asked.

Comment: Hmmm. Tried both options, and when I re-open the modal the next time around, it's still loading up the time of day part of the wizard, so the last step - rather than re-opening at step 1. The good news is the selections are cleared. Now I just need it to re-open at step1.

Comment: @Muirik answer updated to manually remove classes added by tabs functionality. I think the reason that `.tab('show')` isn't just doing the trick is because usually it is called on the tab not the tab content, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/#via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$('body').on('hidden', '.modal', function() {
         $('form')[0].reset();
  });
```

Comment: That appears to freeze the modal. The next time I open the modal by clicking on "repeat-every" the screen goes dark and freezes.

Comment: @Muirik,try with the second solution i.e $("#scheduleModal").html("");

Comment: Tried that, too. Same result.

Comment: @Muirik..try this one edited the answer.first hide the modal and then empty the html in it

Comment: The modal's already been closed. The issue is setting the modal back to it's default state after the outer form is saved. So that the next time the modal is opened it's back to its virgin state.

Comment: @Muirik Happy to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205680/discussion-between-ishwar-gagare-and-muirik).